# Save pandas table (filled with strings) as png

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

This is my code:

```
column1 = ['Measured Set', '1. set', '2. set', '3. set']
column2= ['Breached parameter (number of breaches, %)' ]
column3 = ['Breached parameter (number of breaches, %)']

for j in range(NOT):
    column2.append(report_str[0][j])
    column3.append(report_str[1][j])

data = {
    'Sensor': column1,
    'Sensor 1': column2,
    'Sensor 2': column3,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

`report_str` is a list, filled with strings from which I copy certain strings into the table.

I tried this to save the table with this code:

```
ax = df.plot()
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig('asdf.png')
```

But I get an error: "Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot".

This is my output table that I want to save:
[image]

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all your columns lists have to be the same length. You may plot table with matplotlib and `table` function from pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from pandas.tools.plotting import table

# I add None value to align all lists
column1 = ['Measured Set', '1. set', '2. set', '3. set']
column2= ['Breached parameter (number of breaches, %)', None, None,None ]
column3 = ['Breached parameter (number of breaches, %)', None, None,None]

data = {
    'Sensor': column1,
    'Sensor 1': column2,
    'Sensor 2': column3,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# set fig size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 3)) 
# no axes
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)  
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)  
# no frame
ax.set_frame_on(False)  
# plot table
tab = table(ax, df, loc='upper right')  
# set font manually
tab.auto_set_font_size(False)
tab.set_fontsize(8) 
# save the result
plt.savefig('table.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this code does work but the table stays small even if the text is larger, is there a way to increase the size of rows and columns?

Answer (score 1):

if you get the next exception:
"no module named pandas.tools"

use the following import:
from pandas.plotting import table

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python library called `df2img` available at https://pypi.org/project/df2img/ (disclaimer: I'm the author). It's a wrapper/convenience function using `plotly` as backend.

You can find the documentation at https://df2img.dev.

```
import pandas as pd

import df2img

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=dict(
        float_col=[1.4, float("NaN"), 250, 24.65],
        str_col=("string1", "string2", float("NaN"), "string4"),
    ),
    index=["row1", "row2", "row3", "row4"],
)
```

Saving a `pd.DataFrame` as a .png-file can be done fairly quickly. You can apply formatting, such as background colors or alternating the row colors for better readability.

```
fig = df2img.plot_dataframe(
    df,
    title=dict(
        font_color="darkred",
        font_family="Times New Roman",
        font_size=16,
        text="This is a title",
    ),
    tbl_header=dict(
        align="right",
        fill_color="blue",
        font_color="white",
        font_size=10,
        line_color="darkslategray",
    ),
    tbl_cells=dict(
        align="right",
        line_color="darkslategray",
    ),
    row_fill_color=("#ffffff", "#d7d8d6"),
    fig_size=(300, 160),
)

df2img.save_dataframe(fig=fig, filename="plot.png")
```

[image: pd.DataFrame png file]